# delete an elemnt from an array inside another array with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

hello everyone i have a document of materiels where each document has an array of articles and each article has an array of details here's my collection data:

```
{
"_id": "62f2404b42556d62e2939466",
"code": "120K",
"designation": "PIZZA",
"article": [
{
"etat": "Reçu",
"lot": "",
"marque": "Royal",
"fournisseur": "maatalah",
"dateachat": "2022-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"bc": null,
"bl": null,
"fc": null,
"quantite": 12,
"_id": "62f25d001a035d017369e1f8",
"detail": [
{
"serie": "12",
"ddp": "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"_id": "62f3986fe462b8a173c7d220"
},
{
"serie": "13",
"ddp": "2023-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"_id": "62f39cc1862c1bf5bc40157a"
}
]
},
{
"etat": "Reçu",
"lot": "",
"marque": "margarita",
"fournisseur": "",
"dateachat": "2022-08-04T00:00:00.000Z",
"bc": null,
"bl": null,
"fc": null,
"quantite": 13,
"_id": "62f25d041a035d017369e1fb",
"detail": [
{
"serie": "12345",
"ddp": "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
"_id": "62f281158a159e976c7c68d5"
}
]
}
],
"qteglobal": 25,
"id": "62f2404b42556d62e2939466"
}
```

i want to remove an element from the detail array here my express js code:

```
const { id, idarticle, iddetail } = req.params;
  const materiel = Materiel.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: id, "article._id": idarticle, "article.detail._id": iddetail },
    { $pull: { "article.$.detail": { _id: iddetail } } },

    { new: true }
  );
```

there is no syntax error but the document it doesn't seem to be deleted.
Can anyone help me please ? thank you

Comment: Have you tried findOneAndDelete: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/?

Comment: no but i don't want to delete the whole document i just wannna delete the item from the detail array

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys after trying some methods i end up with this solution:

```
const { id, idarticle, iddetail } = req.params;

  await Materiel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      id,
      "article._id": idarticle,
    },
    {
      $pull: {
        "article.$[].detail": {
          _id: iddetail,
        },
      },
    }
  );
```